# How come été is replaced by Ã©tÃ© in firefox?

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding

It's in a php-file that renders html. I understand that it's an text-encoding-problem. I currently use utf-8. The text is rendered as a regular p-tag in the html. I also use

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

In my head-tag

Comment: The symptom indicates quite clearly that the enconding is wrong. Perhaps the data is double-encoded? Perhaps something is overriding your meta tag?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the encoding of the file itself (open using NotePad++ or some other editor with encoding options, and choose Encoding-> UTF8 without BOM)
2. make sure you have `<! DOCTYPE html>` on the star of the HTML's output

Comment: I checked the encoding in sublime text2, no bom, just utf-8 I also have a doctype.